# How does Apple change site based on whether Javascript is enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a site that will involve a lot of Javascript to show/hide elements in accordions, as well as other things. I want to make sure that even people that do not have Javascript enabled will be able to access all of the site's content (even if it is a little less pretty/interactive). I am not sure the best way to go about doing this. I know you can use the  tag, but I know that cannot be the best way. It doesn't make sense to have to essentially have two versions of the site, one for Javascript and one for not.

As I am still building the site, I thought using Apple's site would be a good example. On any of their product pages (say http://www.apple.com/ipod/) they have their products at the top and then other options (Applications, iTunes & More, etc.) that when you click it shows these next elements. It looks awesome. But if you have Javascript enabled, you no longer get the cool interactive interface, but you do have all the products in a list. How would you go about doing this?

The solution doesn't necessarily have to be the way that Apple does it. I just thought it was a good example to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Comment: it's called "progressive enhancement". Spit out a plain-jane "would work in Netscape 2.x" type page, then use various bits of CSS and Javascript to add enhancements. That way, someone on a brain-dead/old browser at least gets the information, and people with a more modern system get a better experience.

Comment: I'm a big proponent of progressive enhancement. I use it all the time on my sites for CSS3, etc. In this case, I agree it is a certain level of progressive enhancement, but I don't think I want a plain, very basic version of the site for people with Javascript disabled, when 95% of the site would work just fine. I need a way to show the content in a different way like Apple does, while not effecting the overall design more than necessary.

Comment: @Andrew, what you're talking about sounds more like Graceful Degradation.

Comment: @Ates Goral, yes graceful degradation would be more appropriate!

Comment: @alex Wow, my bad, I had totally no idea that I was supposed to click the check mark to accept the answer. I though a moderator went through the site. I will definitely go back and select the answers that are correct. Sorry about that! I absolutely appreciate this community and the help they provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to Check if browser has javascript enabled. You can use the below function and onload it in your body tag. Based on whether the browser has js enabled or disabled, you can either redirect user to another page or do other things.

```
<body onload="checkJs()">
<div id="jsEnabled" style="visibility:hidden">JavaScript enabled</div>
<div id="jsDisabled">JavaScript disabled</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checkJs()
{
document.getElementById("jsEnabled").style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById("jsDisabled").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With js enabled, look at the HTML of the UL elements that contains all those Apple products:

```
<ul class="ul-slider" page="1" style="width: 840px; margin: 0pt 70px;">
```

The other UL is hidden until you click on it. The CSS of the child LI elements makes all of them flow left to right:

```
.productbrowser li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

Now disable javascript and look at the same UL elements. Both are visible and there's no style attribute. So they're using **progressive enhancement**: only add features/effects if the browser supports it.

Start with the frame of mind that JS is disabled and write the HTML & CSS that way. That's the best way to make sure your site works with the LCD. Libraries like Modernizr and Head JS allow you to write CSS rules and conditional javascript based on what the browser and user settings are capable of displaying and the kind of javascript it can handle.